# Is it possible to simulate a fixed FPS through a glass?

Tags: optics

I was wondering if it is possible to simulate frames per second when looking through a glass. I know for example that you can achieve a similar effect with a strobe light and a dark room: the very quick flashes of light give the impression of a succession of frames to the human eye. I was wondering if it is possible to reproduce the same effect in broad daylight; a glass or maybe some other material that quickly switches between allowing and blocking light through is what naturally came to mind, but I am curious about other solutions as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To obtain a stroboscopic effect in those conditions, a spinning wheel with holes on its border is enough.

Comment: could you add more to this answer? it would be helpful to make it clearer.

Comment: I am aware of the effect you are describing but this has nothing to do with my question. I am not asking about a specific object that exhibits this behaviour, rather if it is possible to simulate it through a glass or some sort of frame

Comment: @nazrhom You mean like liquid crystals in active 3D glasses?